# live search bootstrap with ajax and query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Me and some mates have been trying to make a live search script on our search bar. Now this isn't going that well so now we are asking for ur help!

our external file to get the results is this :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*', '*', '*');

$key=$_POST['search'];

$query = ("select name, url from search where name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
$sql = $con->query($query);

while($row = $sql->fetch_array()){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

and our script code looks like this :

```
        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

$( "#formGroupInputLarge" ).keyup(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keyup() called." )
        var string = $('#formGroupInputLarge').val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'search.php',
                    data: {'search': string},
                    success: function(data){
                        var text= JSON.parse(data);
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html("<a href='#'>"+ text +"</a>");
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        }
                }
            );
        }); 

    });
    </script>
```

we've tried with multiple things like  the next ones :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#formGroupInputLarge").keyup(function () {
        console.log("Handler for .keyup() called.");
        var string = $('#formGroupInputLarge').val();
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'search.php',
                data: {'search': string},
                success: function (data) {

                    var obj = eval('('+ data +')' );
                    console.log(obj['name']);
                    //var text = JSON.parse(data);
                    //$("#suggesstion-box").show();
                    //$("#suggesstion-box").html(text);
                    //$("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
                }
            }
        );
    });

});

</script>
```

but none of it seems to work. Please help us!

Comment: `none of it seems to work` is not a reasonable problem statement. You have multiple layers here... dom events, ajax send...server processing...ajax receive ... need to narrow this down. The built in browser dev tools is where you need to start. At least determine if requests are being made or not

Comment: @charlietfl could u maybe shoot as in a good direction? we tried google and learned a bout about jquery/ajax but it is hard to learn (thats our opinion on it)

Comment: I did...look in browser dev tools network (F12) and see if requests are being made...also check for console errors. Read up on how the console works ... it's your first line of troubleshooting. Need to narrow down which part of the chain is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many things could be wrong in your code ! 
You need to give more info on how each part behaves (error messages, etc).

Check this to get a good look at how everything work with AJAX, and nice and simple examples http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you, we will try to learn a bit more about ajax and then if it doesn't work out we will come with better scripts!

Comment: NP ! Try hard and try harder !
Also instead of using 
`$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*', '*', '*');`
Have a look at the PDO Object
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.3

Comment: i normally use PDO as personal opinion in my code. But since the group voted mysqli i didn't really have a choose :p but i will show them the link! maybe it will change there opinions!